# AlertController trying to be presented on view not in window hierarchy

Tags: swift, alert

Trying to figure out why I am getting this error. I have a single view application with two viewcontrollers. I have a segue to the second vc on a button touch:

```
@IBAction func showAccount(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toAccountFromRoot", sender: self)
}
```

I have a facade pattern set up with a Controller file and several helper files. I set the Controller up on the AccountViewController file:

```
let myController = Controller.sharedInstance
```

One of the helper files is to set up a central AlertController for simplified alerts (no extra buttons). It has one method, presentAlert that takes a few arguments, alert title, messsage, presenter.

On my AccountViewController I am attempting to present an alert using this code:

```
myController.alert.presentAlert("No Agent", "You have not registered an agent yet.", self)
```

and in the AlertManager file, presentAlert looks like this:

```
func presentAlert(_ title:String, _ message:String, _ presenter:UIViewController) {

    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    myAlert.addAction(okAction)

    presenter.present(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

I've done this in quite a few apps without an issue so I am confused as to why the compiler thinks the AccountViewController view is not in the window hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Dang it, typed all that and then I solved it 5 seconds later. Just in case someone else runs into the same problem, I was trying to present the alert in viewDidLoad, should of been doing it in viewDidAppear.